# Node express mono + session management + store user details into session table

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, session, express-session

I am using node js with express also mongoDb using.. When I loggedIn the session storing into sessions collection(table) like below

```
{_id: "1233..",session : "{ "cookie" : { "originalMaxAge" : null , "expire3s" : null, "httpOnly" : "true", "path": "/"} }, expires  : 2020-03-27 }
```

But I am trying to achieve how many browsers/device loggedIn same user at the same time.. How we can store user details like user-id or email store into session table?

If i stored those details then I will get the total count of the records to the particular user.. Or have any best approach to do this..

```
import session from 'express-session';
import passport from 'passport';

app.use(passport.initialize());

  app.use(session({
    secret: config.secrets.session,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    store: new MongoStore({
      mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
      db: 'test'
    })
  }));
```

Comment: I think you need to define your assumptions first, what happens to users that clear their cookies? how do we relate to those? how do you define a session? if i log in leave and come back 2minutes later is it a different session? do you log "end" session event? what happens if i log from multiple devices at the same time?

Comment: 1. We are storing the sessions in DB right. Once user loggedIn and comeback after 2 minutes same session only will treat.. until user loggedout.. Once user logged out or session time expired then it treat as session expired/deleted..